# Facebook page plugin / feed links not working on iphone x safari

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, mobile, safari

I installed the Page plugin on my website using this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ it seems to work across multiple devices & browsers. However it doesnt work on another persons iphone x in safari. Cant replicate on browserstack. When the links in the feed are clicked, it just reloads the feed. On other devices it works as intended & takes the user to that page. Has anyone else had this issue? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently its related to an IOS update.